# I want to create a column which has the cumulative sum of values of another column in sas

Tags: sas

I want to create a column which has the cumulative sum of values of another column in sas

Comment: You could start by Googling `create a column which has the cumulative sum of values of another column in sas`. This is not a good question for Stack Overflow, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
data cum_val;
    set sashelp.air;
    cum_air + air;
run;
```

For more details: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/a001354482.htm